# what method of main activity executes when application closes?

Tags: android, android-activity

Can anybody tell me what method of an activity executes when an application closes?. like i have a main activity and if i press back button on my phone. The Application closes so i want to know what method executes at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method should be called when your application is preparing to go into the background. In the case where you hit the back button, [`onStop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29) should also be called. However, it is not necessarily guaranteed that `onStop()` will be called in all situations (such as low memory situations) since an application may be killed to reclaim resources at any point after `onPause()` has returned.

See also: [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).